I disabled automatic data conversion in Excel but my ID numbers are still converted to Scientific notation
Excel has the nasty habit of trying to be clever and consider any string of digits as a number. I deal a lot with data that include ID numbers and Phone numbers. These are text strings although they seem like numbers to Excel. So, it goes ahead without my permission and converts these columns to number format.
Our national IDs have 16 digits. So, by converting this to a number, you irreversibly lose the 16th digit since Excel only can accommodate 15-digit integers.
For phone numbers, the issue is not too bad since these are 10 digits. Still, it annoys me that the leading 0 is stripped away.
In the new version of Office365, Microsoft claims to have addressed this annoyance. I disabled all automatic data conversions as you can see in this image and yet the issue persists.
What could I be missing?


Are you sure cells are in General or Text format before entering the data? If there is a Number format the option doesn't work.

What type of file are you opening and how are you opening it? Is the file type associated with Excel?

See if this provides insight. I noticed a note indicating settings are ignored during macro execution and another stating settings are enforced after initial file opening: https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/control-data-conversions-in-excel-for-windows-and-mac

Use the Text format, not the General format.

Or precede number with single quote, ', to prevent interpretation.

To all those saying "make sure the cells are in Text format before entering data"; who does that? Normally we don't enter data manually into excel; we just get data from somewhere else and open it with Excel for exploration and analysis. The comment from @bugdrown gives a good insight on what might have gone wrong. My data is in CSV format and when I open it with Excel, that's when the conversion happen since that checkbox is not checked.

FWIW, I removed .csv file association with Excel and use Excel Get and Transform (Data tab) to get data from .csv files and revise data types before loading to a sheet. It helps avoid the .csv conversion shenanigans. The convenience of double clicking on a .csv file is seldom worthwhile.
